# Open FullCalendar (from URL lin) to a specific month/year?

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to provide a link from an external website to my website's FullCalendar calendar page, but I want to the calendar to open to a specific month and year.

I envision a URL crafted similarly to:

http://mywebsite/calendarpage?month=5&year=2016

Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO, @ricks99. Yes. It is. What did you try so far?  "Don't ask about questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)" http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Thanks Mario. I've tried adding "month" and "year" to the URL but they obviously didn't work. I reviewed the docs (http://fullcalendar.io/docs/) but there's no mention of passing a URL parameter in order to have the calendar open to a specific month/year. I've tried digging through the JS to see if I could figure out what variable to pass. 

You say that "It is [possible]" to do what I want. Can you tell me how?

Answer (score 6):

First of all you should get your parameters from the URL. That could depend on the structure of your website.

For example, you can use [this method if you are using JQUERY](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/get-url-parameters-using-jquery.html). Once you have your parameters, need to send the data to the fullcalendar.

Now you have two options, if you have already loaded the calendar, you can move to a specific date using [gotoDate](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/gotoDate/)

```
var ricksDate = new Date(2016, 5, 1);
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', ricksDate);
```

...or  if fullcalendar need to be initialised, set the default date to your specific date. You need to add the specific line when loading the calendar:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: ricksDate; 
    })
```

Comment: If you have a WP site be careful using the OPs query string of http://mywebsite/calendarpage?month=5&year=2016 as soon as you have a query string with ?year your site will look for WP posts and the other vars in there will send you to a 404 page you will most likely need to use y=2016 or similar to make it work.